# What is the difference between using spread props before or after className in a React span element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i am new to React and javascript development and would like to know the difference between

```
var a = { className: 'my-secondary-classname' }; 
<span className="my-span-classname" {...a}>abc</span>
```

and

```
var a = { className: 'my-secondary-classname' }; 
<span {...a} className="my-span-classname">abc</span>
```

Tried reading about spread props and still not clear about it

Comment: It will override your props if you populate it after. In this case your `className` will be override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

className is a prop. SO if you do `{...a}` and a is an object that contains className as a property, the value of `a.classname` will be applied to that component.

If you do className before `{...a}`, `a.className` will override the previously supplied classname.

If you do className after `{...a}`, className will override `a.className`

```
const myClass = () => {
    let a = { className = "w-full bg-red", key: 1 };

    return (
        <div>
           <p {...a} className="bg-blue">Hello world</p> {/* this will have a blue background */}
           <p className="bg-blue" {...a} >Hello world</p> {/* this will have a red background */}
        </div>
}
```

Comment: that's no worries, would you mind marking it as the answer so others can see it

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator here is no different to a spread on an object, as that's what your doing.

So the spread will evaluate from left to right, so everything to the right will take precedence.

eg..

```js
const a = {test: '123', other: 'other'};

console.log({...a, test: '321'});
console.log({test: '321', ...a});
```

Notice how the first spread, we get '321', and the second one it keeps the '123'.

To prove this is just the same as spreading an object, here is what the JSX for your first one looks like ->

```
"use strict";
var a = { className: 'my-secondary-classname' };
React.createElement("span", Object.assign({}, a, { className: "my-span-classname" }), "abc");
//Note Object.Assign, is the alternative to using spread on older browsers
//So the above is also the same as.
React.createElement("span", {...a,className: "my-span-classname"}, "abc");
```

So internally that JSX just gets converted into a `Object.assign()` -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

> Properties in the target object are overwritten by properties in the
> sources if they have the same key. Later sources' properties overwrite
> earlier ones.

Comment: I understand this concept now thank you